# How to prevent ListView items highlighting in Black

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have been trying desperately to fix this issue where my ListView items are highlighted.  I have reviewed any solution I could find here on stackoverflow, and have found none that work for me.

First off, this is a ListView in a LinearLayout in a ViewPager in a LinearLayout.

Each Item in that Listview is a LinearLayout containing a LinearLayout (Containing a TextView) and a Gallery.  The Gallery contains multiple LinearLayouts containing a TextView and Imageview in a FrameLayout.

This problem occurs, not on click but on drag, as when swiping your finger over a story (sometimes while the ListView scrolls with your drag) the item underneath becomes selected.  Additionally, this particular problem only occurs on devices where the over-scroll effect does not cause a bounce when scrolling.

Attempts to solve the issue are as follows:

- Set the List Selector to the Background Color in XML (Fail)
- Set the List Select to Alpha #00000000 in XML (Fail)
- The Above but Programatically
- The Above but by theme
- Code that sets the selection to -1 onListItemClick
- Removing the background from list item's LinearLayout (Works on 4.0)
- Setting `android:cacheColorHint` to `#00000000` (does nothing?)

I just can't figure out why it's doing this and I really need it to stop.

[image: Screenshot of ListView Item being HIghlighted]

Comment: When you add an item to the list that is clickable it disables the listSelection, I guess you could abuse this or look more into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a most interesting problem.  The solution of which is even more interesting.

For some reason, what I didn't try, and what nobody thought of, was to remove `android:background` from the `LinearLayout` for the ListView items.

Upon removing `android:background`, the layout continues to display properly and the black no longer appears.

If you have a problem similar to this that this does not solve, you may want to check the Android Blog: [Why is my list black?](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

**EDIT:** This worked fine for ICS, but elicited a much larger problem in 2.1.  To completely solve the ordeal, I ended up having to specify `android:cacheColorHint="#000000"` to the `ListView` (and the `LinearLayout` for good measure) in my inline styles as well as in the style definition I applied to the `ListView`.

Comment: in facts the cache color hint must be set to `#00000000`, not `#000000`